# OpenCV - segmenting tree from the image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to segment the color green in the HSV-color space. I have this image of a tree and I would only like the upper part of the tree to be left.

[image]

This is the image I am starting from and the mask I obtain is just an entirely black image
This is my current code:

```
Mat input = imread(image_location);
imshow("input img",input); waitKey(0);


//convert image to HSV
Mat input_hsv;
cvtColor(input,input_hsv,COLOR_BGR2HSV);


vector<Mat>channels;
split(input_hsv, channels);

Mat H = channels[0];
Mat S = channels[1];
Mat V = channels[2];

Mat mask2;

inRange(input_hsv, Scalar(70, 0, 0), Scalar(143, 255, 255), mask2);


imshow("mask2", mask2);waitKey(0);
```

Normally the color green in HSV ranges from +/- 70 to 140.
But it doesn't seem to work at all. Could somebody help?

Comment: try coding the formula of converting RGB to HSV for green color

Comment: @JeruLuke I don't see how that could help. I right now just did the conversion from RGB to HSV online. The color green has its hue from 70 to 140 and I allowed the saturation and S- component to be any value. Would you mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: *saturation and V-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working in `8U`. Thus, the H component which is normally in degrees [0,360) [is compressed to fit 255 by halving](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hsv).

See docs: ***8-bit images: V←255V,S←255S,H←H/2(to fit to 0 to 255)***

So the original H green range [70,140] should be halved to [35,70].

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just accepted it. Encountered another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789983/opencv-dilatation-doesnt-seem-to-work

Any idea's?

Comment: the page does not open